Toe kick vent for larger AC return?
I’m in the process of designing some built-in cabinetry, but one of the cabinet boxes would be in front of a 23”x23” HVAC return. Would a long toe kick vent at the base of the cabinet offer sufficient airflow?
Alternatively, would running some ductwork from the toe kick vent to the return or would just leaving that cabinet open on the inside do the trick?

Please read Triplefault's answer carefully.  It is a bad idea to cover the return with cabinetry.

Got pics of the location and a sketch of the cabinetry?

A 23"x23" opening is 529 square inches of area for airflow. Whatever openings you allow, be sure they are more than 529 square inches in area.
A 4" toekick has to be open for 132 1/4" to allow the 529 sq-in airflow. A 6" kick should be 88-ish inches long. (This is not taking into account airflow friction in a long, thin opening. More space should be allowed.)
You should also allow such space behind the cabinet for airflow too, so the wood "duct" you design into the cabinet will rather strongly impinge on the insides of the cabinet.
Putting cabinets in front of this return duct will require a lot of open space to not restrict that 529 sq-in airflow. Perhaps a redesign is necessary, or move the return duct, too.
